# Basic variable assignment issue (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure what's happening but simply trying to set a variable and then assign it a value but it's like the value doesn't take hold. I'm trying to achieve something more complex but below just demonstrates what's happening even with simple code.

The screenshot shows how the num var is still at 0 when it should be 3. The code is ok so what have a I done? Not getting any errors.

Many thanks in adavance

```
Sub getRundownTimes()

Dim num As Integer
num = 1
num = num + 2

End Sub
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Tried using different variable types with no luck and restarting excel just in case it was a bug.

Comment: The screenshot shows the initial (default) value of `num`. Either use the locals window or `Debug.Print num` as the last statement and see its value in the immediate window.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the code before any statement is executed. `Num` is a local variable and in VBA it is initialized with 0. If you step thru the code with the debugger (use F8), you will see that it first will get 1 and then 3. This value remains until the routine is done, after that the variable "is forgotten". Next time you call the routine, everything starts again (0 - 1 - 3). If you want the value to "survive" the end of the routine, either declare it as static or as global variable.

Comment: Are you requiring to keep its value when getRundownTimes has gone out of scope?  If so check out Static variables.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no problem, you know: you are showing the situation when the procedure is not run yet. If you debug further (pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>), you'll end up with a situation like this one:

[image]

(In the watch-window you clearly see that the value of `num` now equals 3)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output in a pop-up window when you run the macro, you can use the MsgBox function to display a message box with the value of num. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
    Sub getRundownTimes()
    Dim num As Integer
    num = 1
    num = num + 2
    MsgBox "The value of num is: " & num
    End Sub
```